# bcp utlity SQLState = 07006, NativeError = 0

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is the error that I am getting while executing `bcp` command:

> SQLState = 07006, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Serve owed from the given field type 0x3D for
>   field 9 to column 9.

**command used is** :

```
bcp "VM_Asia.dbo.dim_budget" in C:\BCP_DATA_INDIA\datafile\dim_budget.dat -f C:\BCP_DATA_INDIA\formatcorrected\Dim_budget.fmt -T
```

And my `fmt` file is like this:

```
11.0
12
1       SQLINT              0       4       ""   1     budget_SK                                  ""
2       SQLINT              1       4       ""   2     country_sk                                 ""
3       SQLINT              0       4       ""   3     budget_ID                                  ""
4       SQLNCHAR            2       36      ""   4     budget_Type                                Latin1_General_CI_AI
5       SQLNCHAR            2       200     ""   5     budget_Description                         Latin1_General_CI_AI
6       SQLDATE             1       3       ""   6     budget_Applied_From                        ""
7       SQLDATE             1       3       ""   7     budget_Applied_To                          ""
8       SQLDATETIME         1       8       ""   8     Inserted_Date                              ""
9       SQLDATETIME         1       8       ""   9     Modified_Date                              ""
10      SQLINT              1       4       ""   10    batchno                                    ""
11      SQLINT              1       4       ""   11    Status                                     ""
12      SQLINT              1       4       ""   12    company_id                                 ""
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you on? Possible explanation here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677301.aspx

SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) is not supported beyond SQL Server 2012. Avoid using SNAC in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. The Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server provides native connectivity from Windows to Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Azure SQL Database.